# Unable to recover remote 'origin' on Gitlab Runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab Runner with the `docker` executor and set up one of my script commands as:

```
script:
  - git remote remove origin
```

(I was experimenting with changing the remote to a URL with a token so that I can push a tag through a pipeline build)

And now my Gitlab Runner is broken in running my builds

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.0.0 (5396d320)
  on docker-runner01 ed123asf
Using Docker executor with image private-repo.org/node-app:node8 ...
Pulling docker image private-repo.org/node-app:node8 ...
Using docker image sha256:1e20n89128907j9d817h123091728 for private-repo.org/node-app:node8 ...
Running on runner-ed123asf-project-620-concurrent-0 via docker-runner01...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at ash1234 My last commit
fatal: No such remote 'origin'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Does anyone know how to go from here? I tried restarting my Gitlab runner and removing the Image, but it seems like the problem is with the Git settings that I can't find anywhere.

Comment: I found this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy
And changing it to `clone` works, though this strategy is noted to be slower than `fetch`. And this feature is also noted to be an experimental feature, so it might be removed in the future too. This will be my workaround for now. "variables: GIT_STRATEGY: clone"